# Calculating coefficient of determination given alpha and mean

Tags: statistics, linear-regression

While trying a data science quiz on analyticsvidya.com, I came across the following question:

Consider the following sample: 1,2,3,4,5,6. Alpha = 0.05 and the population mean is equal to 4.5. Calculate the coefficient of determination for this data. The answer given is 0.25

I thought coefficient of determination was a property of a regression. That is, relation between two variables. Is there another interpretation of coefficient of determination that applies to a single series?